# Highlight a button when it pressed without using two drawable?

Tags: android, button, drawable

before I use two drawable one when the button state is pressed and an another another as default. so I'm fabricating a hole new image just for simple effect ! So now I'm asking...

is it possible to applicate (a color filter or any effect) on the button drawable when that button is pressed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best way to do it !

```
Drawable drawableNotPressed = button.getBackground(); 
Drawable drawable = drawableNotPressed.getCurrent();

//use a filter 
drawable.setColorFilter(0xF00, Mode.MULTIPLY);
StateListDrawable listDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
listDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);
listDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.defaultValue }, drawableNotPressed );
button.setBackgroundDrawable(listDrawable);
```

et Voila !

Answer (score 3):

Or you can also rather than using setOnClickListner use setOnTouchListener to gain the desired effect using only one image

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.testBth)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

      @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
              Button view = (Button) v;
              view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
              v.invalidate();
              break;
          }
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              // Your action here on button click
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
              Button view = (Button) v;
              view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
              view.invalidate();
              break;
          }
          }
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Those who are struggling why colorFilter is not working. Please use invalidate(), it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If your button is the standard gray background you can apply a filter in the `onClick` method for the button to change the color...

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);  //Green
```

To clear the filter later:

```
button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

Comment: the idea of filter is nice, but it's implimentation on click is not good cause the button can be pressed but not clicked... can I listen the press action ?

Comment: I'm sure you can, I've not done that before so I have no firsthand experience to share regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the button's style in one of the setOn*Listener Methods

Comment: setOnKeyListener for exemple ? and listen to KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN and KeyEvent.ACTION_UP ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: @M'hamed maybe the setOnTouchListener, but I'm not sure.