# How to change color of button when clicked through XML only (without another drawable)?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, imagebutton

I want to change the color of a button when it's pressed or focused, or in fact, any state. However, I want to do it not only through XML, but also without using another drawable. Previous questions that address this, like [Highlight a button when it pressed without using two drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760943/highlight-a-button-when-it-pressed-without-using-two-drawable) and [How to Change color of Button in Android when Clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked)  do it either programmatically without drawables, or with drawables through XML. Is there a property I can set in a button.xml file or something that can change the background color of the view when highlighted or clicked, without consulting Java?

Here is the code to my activity_main.xml. If it's not completely obvious already, I'm using a static image for the game board to a phone tic-tac-toe game.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gameboard"
    android:src="@drawable/gameboard" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="288dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="219dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/top_left"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squareOne"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareOne"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="108dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/top_middle"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squareTwo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareTwo"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/top_right"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareFour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/squareOne"
    android:layout_below="@+id/squareTwo"
    android:layout_marginBottom="179dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/middle_left"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareFive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squareFour"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/squareTwo"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/squareTwo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareFour"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/middle"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareSix"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/squareThree"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareFive"
    android:layout_marginBottom="178dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/middle_right"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareSeven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/squareFour"
    android:layout_below="@+id/squareFive"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bottom_left"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareEight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squareSeven"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/squareFive"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/squareFive"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareSeven"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareNine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/squareEight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/squareSix"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/squareEight"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bottom_right"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I use a blank_button.png file and stretch it over each square on the gameBoard ImageView. I know I know from all you haters that I should be using relative layouts instead, but I'm only looking for this app to run on a particular kind of device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state maybe this can help you?

Comment: i see what you are getting at. I tried making two separate xml files, one for the button states and one for the the highlighted image. I tried tiling the small square with `android:tileMode="repeat"`. I tried referencing this in the layout file. However, this just puts a small square on each of the larger stretched out buttons. This still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By xml,you can search by google.I will show you one way to solve the problem.
[A forum which mentioned this problem](http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-323138-1-1.html)

Of course,if you don't use xml,you must change this to java code.It's simple,but this means it won't show complex effects.

Supplement：Override the onStateChange method,you should override your widget.

Comment: I know how to solve it via java. I just want it to be preloaded on onCreate when I call setContentView. There has to be a solution to this via xml, I already googled it for a while, so I'm hoping that someone with a good amount of experience can answer this.